# Member functions of a templated class, that take a template type as argument

Tags: c++, templates, function, types, member

I have a node struct and stack class. When I put the definition for 'void Push(T data)' outside the class definition I get:

```
error: 'template<class T> class Stack' used without template parameters
```

But when I put it inside the class definition it works fine.
Here is the code:

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    Node(T data, Node <T> * address) : Data(data), p_Next(address) {}
    T Data;
    Node <T> * p_Next;
};

template <class T> 
class Stack
{
public:

    Stack() : size(0) {}
    void Push(T data);
    T Pop();

private:
    int size;
    Node <T> * p_first;
    Node <T> * p_last;  
};
```

The implementation for Push(T data) is :

```
void Stack::Push(T data)
{
    Node <T> * newNode;   

    if(size==0)
        newNode = new Node <T> (data, NULL);
    else
        newNode = new Node <T> (data, p_last);

    size++;
    p_last = newNode;
}
```

Edit: The solutions worked except that now I get a linking error whenever I try to call the functions.

```
Stack<int>::Pop", referenced from   
_main in main.o   
symbol(s) not found.
```

unless the definitions are in Stack.h instead of Stack.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `template <class T>` again (and then use that `T` again as the template parameter for the class):

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::Push(T data)
{
    Node <T> * newNode;   

    if(size==0)
        newNode = new Node <T> (data, NULL);
    else
        newNode = new Node <T> (data, p_last);

    size++;
    p_last = newNode;
}
```

Comment: @user4: do you know why I might be getting the linking error?

Comment: It's an unfortunate side effect of the way templates are implemented in C++.  Since the parameters must be known at compile time, you can't compile the template code and then link other code to it after, as the compiler must know the specific instantiations from the subsequent file to create for the first file, but once it gets to the subsequent file it's too late. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13 for a full explanation and workarounds.

Comment: @user4: would it be considered an appropriate solution then to just put the function definitions in Stack.h along with the class definition?

Comment: @Matt In this case, yes, since there's really no other way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a template statement before member functions when defined outside of the class...

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::Push(T data)
{
    Node <T> * newNode;   

    if(size==0)
        newNode = new Node <T> (data, NULL);
    else
        newNode = new Node <T> (data, p_last);

    size++;
    p_last = newNode;
}
```

(At least it should be similar to this.)

Comment: It worked, except that it wont let me call the functions if the definions are in Stack.cpp, while it does work if the definition is in Stack.h. I get the linking error: "Stack<int>::Pop", referenced from _main in main.o symbol(s) not found. But I can call non-member functions from Stack.cpp.

Comment: The real-world implementations of C++ templates require the implementation code to be in the header.  An example of this can be found in the C++ standard library.  If you look at the standard library headers provided with your compiler, you'll notice that class templates have the full class implementation, not just the method declarations. -- The bottom line: put the method definition in the header file also; the linker and compiler should handle the rest.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when the definition is inside the class definition it knows the template parameter. If you want to put the definition outside you need to explicitly tell the compiler that T is a template parameter...

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::Push(T data) {/* code */}
```